# bs4: looping over a range of pages & gathering elements by class into a csv-output

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am trying to scrape a little chunk of information from a site: fetching the data and storing it in CSV-dataset. The project: for a list of contact-data of community-services and official helpdesk in cities and village: - approx 1600 records

the **basic-site:** https://www.service-bw.de/web/guest/trefferliste/-/trefferliste/q-rathaus

**the detail-page:** Rathaus [Gemeinde Grünkraut]
https://www.service-bw.de/web/guest/organisationseinheit/-/sbw-oe/Rathaus-6000566-organisationseinheit-0

note: we have got approximatly 1600 pages.. so one of the main questions is - how to gather them into the show... how to loop over all the pages that contain the data

```
<div class="sp-m-organisationseinheitDetails-basisInfos-content sp-l-grid-container"> 
<div class="sp-l-grid-row"> 
<div class="sp-l-grid-col-md-6 sp-l-grid-col-sm-6 sp-l-grid-xs-col-12"> 
<div> <div itemprop="address" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress" class="sp-m-organisationseinheitDetails-basisInfos-addressBlock"> 
<h4 class="sp-m-organisationseinheitDetails-basisInfos-detailsTitle mdash">Hausanschrift</h4> 
<div itemprop="streetAddress"> <span>Scherzachstr.</span> <span>2</span><br>
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Hausanschrift: 
- name 
- street & housenumber
- postal code & town 


Kontaktmöglichkeiten:
- telehon
- fax
- e-mail 
- internet
```

see in an image the chunk of information which is in every record - in each of the more than 1600 records...:

[image]

**my approach**:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor

url = "https://www.service-bw.de/web/guest/trefferliste/-/trefferliste/q-rathaus{}"


def main(url, num):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        print(f"Collecting Page# {num}")
        r = req.get(url.format(num))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        link = [item.get("href")
                for item in soup.findAll("a", rel="bookmark")]
        return set(link)


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(main, url, num)
               for num in [""]+[f"page/{x}/" for x in range(2, 50)]]

allin = []
for future in futures:
    allin.extend(future.result())


 soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        target = [item.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ") for item in soup.find(
            "h4", class_="sp-m-organisationseinheitDetails-basisInfos-content sp-l-grid-container").find_next("ul").findAll("dd itemprop")[:8]]
        head = [soup.find("h4", class_="plugin-title").text]
        new = [x for x in target if x.startswith(
            ("Telefon", "Fax", "E-Mail", "Internet"))]
        return head + new


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor1:
    futures1 = [executor1.submit(parser, url) for url in allin]

for future in futures1:
    print(future.result())
```

btw. perhaps we re able to get the further (additional content too) - but at the moment i try to figure out to get a basic grip of getting the pages and parsing it generally...

**where i got stuck:**  i get errors: `File "C:\Users\Kasper\Documents_f_s_j_mk__dev_\bs\bw.py", line 28 target = [item.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ") for item in soup.find( ^ IndentationError: unexpected indent [Finished in 0.32s]` but besides this i suspect that the whole code is running well and fetches all the wanted items.

Perhaps you have a hint for me and give some guidance.. thx in advance.

Comment: What's the actual question? Isn't the program you pasted working?

Comment: Hello dear Andrej - many thanks for the reply - great to hear from you - i get errors 
` File "C:\Users\Kasper\Documents\_f_s_j\_mk_\_dev_\bs\bw.py", line 28
    target = [item.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ") for item in soup.find(
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
[Finished in 0.32s]`  but besides this i suspect that the whole code is running well and fetches all the wanted items. I am currently try to debug the stuff - and i am glad for recieving tipps and hints from you. - thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please edit your question and post the error code there? (with correct formatting)

Comment: hello dear Andrej - many thanks i will do so. _ i just muse about the correct editing here in the comments  _ i..e. to use the ´ or the `. but now - first of all i edit the question and add the code that i got back there. Many thanks for your encouraging and the help and this helps me to go ahead scaffolding help and approach -this helps me alot

Comment: question is unclear and long for no reason. even you haven't included your desired output @zero

Comment: hello dear @ αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη  many thanks for the reply - i have tried to clear things in the question - added a desired output - which should be contained in each of the records.  I tried to avoid any misunderstandings - and cleared up (and shortened) the targetet desired output to a concise set of data - that i is wanted. many thanks for your help in advance.  - btw. you see that i have tried to apply earlier coding snippets of your  earlier solutions...;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor
from colorama import Fore, Style


req = requests.Session()

params = {
    "p_p_id": "suchergebnisse_WAR_suchegui",
    "p_p_lifecycle": "2",
    "p_p_state": "normal",
    "p_p_mode": "view",
    "p_p_resource_id": "nextHits",
    "p_p_cacheability": "cacheLevelPage",
    "p_p_col_id": "column-1",
    "p_p_col_count": "1"
}

data = {
    "q": ""
}


def soup(content):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
    target = [item['href']
              for item in soup.select("a[id^=organisationseinheit]")]
    return target


def main(url):
    r = req.get(url)
    urls = soup(r.content)
    print("Extracting Page 1")
    return urls


go = main("https://www.service-bw.de/web/guest/trefferliste/-/trefferliste/q-rathaus")


def second(url):
    links = []
    for page in range(1, 166):
        print(f"Extracting Page {page + 1}")
        r = req.get(url,
                    params=params, data=data)
        urls = soup(r.content)
        links.extend(urls)
    return links


allin = go + second("https://www.service-bw.de/web/guest/trefferliste")


print(f"Catched {len(allin)} Links")


def third(url):
    r = req.get(url)
    parser = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    print(url)
    try:
        part1 = [item.text for item in parser.find("div", itemprop="streetAddress").parent.findAll(
            "span", text=True)]
    except AttributeError:
        part1 = ["N/A"]
    try:
        part2 = [item.text for item in parser.select(
            "dd.sp-l-grid-col-md-7")[:4]]
    except AttributeError:
        part2 = ["N/A"]
    finish = part1+part2
    return finish


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=30) as executor:
    futures = executor.map(third, allin)

    for future in futures:
        print(f"{Fore.GREEN}{future}{Style.RESET_ALL}")
```